# How can I see if 2 pieces of code are equivalent in JavaScript / PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html-entities

I have some Ajaxing going on and I have 2 blocks of source code. The first is:

```
window.lastSavedContents = "<?php echo htmlentities( $contents ); ?>";
```

The second is whatever the user types into a text editor. The problem is `window.lastSavedContents` is `htmlentities` encoded, whereas the second block is not.

How can I check for equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `htmlentities`, but [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), that only encodes `<`, `>`, `&` and `"`. That way, you can simply replace those entities using

```
var decoded = encoded.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
                     .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
                     .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
                     .replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
```

If you still want to use `htmlentities` you can simply create a temporary `div`:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = encoded;
var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either find a way around entity encoding the data, or decode `window.lastSavedContents` in Javascript. Here's a function that will help you do that: http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode:424